# Explain why in the second example the Animal function is not the constructor of the dog object?

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

## The problem

Look at the example #1.

I created a constructor function called `Animal` (I use old school way, without using classes).

Then I defined a `name` property and method called `drink(...)`.

After that I created an instance called `dog`.

Then I just checked if the `drink()` works.

And finally I checked if the `constructor` property of the `dog` is the `Animal` function, and it is. Okay. It worked as expected.

**But. Check out the example #2. Why it gives the opposite, if I do almost the same thing... ?**

### Example #1

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
  
  this.drink = function(liquid) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is drinking ${liquid} ...`);
  }
}


const dog = new Animal("Spike");

dog.drink("vodka")

console.log(dog.constructor === Animal)// TRUE ✔️
```

### Example #2

```js
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype = {
  drink: function(liquid) {
    console.log(`${this.name} is drinking ${liquid} ...`);
  }
}


const dog = new Animal("Spike");

dog.drink("vodka")

console.log(dog.constructor === Animal)// FALSE ❗ But, why?
```

Comment: You're replacing the entire prototype of `Animal` in the second case. `constructor` is no longer there.

Comment: Okay, what do I need to do so it works?

Comment: `Animal.prototype.drink = function(liquid) { console.log(\`${this.name} is drinking   ...\`); }`